# Why Angular 6 app throwing error while deploying for production?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I have integrated ngx-Pagination & it working fine when I test it locally but when I run the command as **ng build --prod** it shows me error *ERROR in ./src/app/myads/myads.component.ngfactory.js* 
 [image: error]

If anybody knows the solution please answer.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from "ngx-Pagination";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,    
    FormsModule,
    NgxPaginationModule    

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {     

 }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  collection = ['r', 'k', 'u', 'jj'];
  constructor() { 

  }


}
```

app.component.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 2, currentPage: p }">Hello</li>
</ul>  
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

Comment: You need to share some code. It is hard to say anything with this little information.

Comment: So, your referring to the `collection` in the app component, but declaring and populating the `collection` in the app module class? Is that working for you?

Comment: please check now

Comment: I believe the error arrised because Angular cannot determine the module for class HomeComponent, which could be fixed by adding said component to an NgModule. Just a wild guess.

Comment: means.........?

Comment: Add HomeComponent to module declarations.

Comment: in app.module.ts file ?

Comment: please check error image again

Comment: sorry it has nothing to do with homecomponent

Comment: please check error image

Comment: The error literally says: 'Add HomeComponent to your NgModule'.

Comment: no I just updated the error image

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a HomeComponent that is not declared in any module?

Try to add HomeComponent in your AppModule declarations

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,    
    FormsModule,
    NgxPaginationModule    

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {     

 }
```

Comment: ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/ngx-Pagination/dist/ngx-pagination.ngfactory' in 'D:\paginationdemo\src\app'

Answer (score 1):

Try **ng build** because the compiler doesn't care whether you have declare variables or not but in prod mode this is set to strict.